# Error "TypeError: records is undefined if (records.length < 1) {" after loading Store in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to move my project from ExtJS 4.1 to 4.2 and I've recieved one strange error. Every time after I've loaded store (I'm using buffered store) to my grid I receive such error

`TypeError: records is undefined`

```
if (records.length < 1) { 
string number 134635
```

[This is link to my grid-making js file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20018982/Chat.js)

[And this is link to my store-init file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20018982/TopicGrid.js)

What it can be?

Comment: A more sizable chunk of your code is needed to figure out the problem.  records is undefined means just that: records was never defined.  If you want more info, give us more to go on.

Comment: I've added links to my code. Can you look it please?

Comment: neither of the linked files contain the code you show. Please show the function in which you're making this call (don't link to the file, just paste that code) and we can probably help you much better. Without any additional information: you get the error because "records" doesn't exist when you call `records.length`.

Comment: The problem is that this code (records.length) is part of ExtJS framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also receiving this error after moving to 4.2 from 4.1, using a buffered store.  It seems to be caused by making a selection in a grid and then calling store.load().  Two workarounds:

1) Add a fix to the extjs source code (ugh) (see this blog post here, use google translate) : http://blog.khodam.org/extjs/upgrade-guide-extjs-4-1-dan-extjs-4-2-menghindari-error-dan-abnormal-behaviour-pada-extjs-4-2-0.php

2) remove the selection before you reload your store, for instance:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().deselectAll(true); 
store.load();
```

(you'll need to use your own grid / store variables, or do lookups with Ext.getCmp() etc).

Comment: Just found a better version of patching the source using an override, from the Sencha forums :  http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258397-4.2.0-RC-Selecting-a-grid-s-row-with-a-buffered-store-causes-a-JavaScript-error/page2

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem, big thanks to George Geczy who has found the [solution](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?258397-4.2.0-RC-Selecting-a-grid-s-row-with-a-buffered-store-causes-a-JavaScript-error/page2) by Daniil at sencha forum.

The best way to solve this is to override 'storeHasSelected' event like this:

```
Ext.selection.Model.override({
    storeHasSelected: function(record) {
        var store = this.store,
            records,
            len, id, i;

        if (record.hasId() && /*store.getById(record)*/ store.getById(record.getId())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            records = store.data.items;
            len = records.length;
            id = record.internalId;

            for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
                if (id === records[i].internalId) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    
});
```

1) I don't advice to edit extjs source code, it may cost many terrible hours of searching "how to fix the fix".

2)  Removing the selection before reloading the store is not enough, it is also needed to override the refresh button in pagingtoolbar.